# python pubsub subscription expiration

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have python code which create both topic and subscription, but I wanted to create the subscription with no expiration date currently, 31 days is the default value for subscription expiration if nothing is given at the time creating the subscription, my python code for the same:

```
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

project_path_topic = publisher.project_path('project')
project_path_sub = subscriber.project_path('project')

topic_path = publisher.topic_path('project', 'topic-name')
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path('project', 'subscription-name')

topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, sub_name)

# topic and sub creation
topic_created = publisher.create_topic(topic_path)
subscription = subscriber.create_subscription(subscription_path, topic_path)
```

Now, I wanted to override the expiration for never but I did not find any existing flag from the document which I could easily set in my python code.

There is the way which [uses command line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/create) but I did not wanted to use that as my whole code is already written in python than why not to deal this through python api only.

Please help if you know how I can achieve it in the python code base, assuming all the langs will going to use same google backend apis only.(I could see that [backend api](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/python/latest/pubsub_v1.projects.subscriptions.html#create) it dealing with expiration policy(expirationPolicy) but did not see the same in [python api doc](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/index.html#creating-a-subscription))

Note - I am creating pull base subscription not push.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very bad documented, but I succeeded! Here the code

```
    update_mask = {"paths": {"expiration_policy"}}
    # expiration_policy = pubsub_v1.types.ExpirationPolicy(ttl= pubsub_v1.types.Duration(seconds=605000))
    expiration_policy = pubsub_v1.types.ExpirationPolicy()
    subscription = pubsub_v1.types.Subscription(name=subscription_path,  expiration_policy=expiration_policy)
    subscription = subscriber.update_subscription(request={"subscription": subscription, "update_mask": update_mask})
```

Comment: I wanted to set subscription expiry to never, at the time of creation only, when I tried this `expiration_policy = pubsub_v1.types.ExpirationPolicy()` for create_subscription I got an error => "TypeError: {'paths': set(['expiration_policy'])} has type dict, but expected one of: bytes, unicode", means I should have some value to be assign for expiration policy I can not set this empty. Do know you what to do now? I will use the update subscription for my existing subscriptions also wanted to deal with the same at creation time as well.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear, I understood that you only wanted to update your subscription. Let me test, I will post an update soon.

Comment: I got it how we can do it for create_subscription as well `subscription = subscriber.create_subscription(name=subscription_path, topic=topic_path, expiration_policy=expiration_policy)`, we do not need any "update_mask" attr to set the expiration_policy for create. Thanks a lot for your help @guillaume

Comment: Good news!! Indeed, the update mask is to indicate to the API what part are you updating. If you create, you don't need it, you create all the part that you provide.